# Ordering Custom Search Results in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

After watch Sebastien Ros's excellent primer on customizing search in Orchard - see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7v5qSR4g7E0 - I have been playing around with creating my own custom search.

This code, excerpted from my SearchController.cs works fine for sorting by create date.

```
if (String.Equals(order, "created", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
searchBuilder = searchBuilder.SortByDateTime("created").Ascending();
}
```

But I need to sort by "title" not create date.  Something like this that actually works.

```
if (String.Equals(order, "title", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
searchBuilder = searchBuilder.SortBy("title");
}
```

My URL string looks like this:
http://localhost:333333//Search/?q=&order=title

Any tips on sorting search in Orchard would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I sorted out this out.  Sorting works fine as above.  My issues with ordering were down to how Lucene was handling or not handling certain characters and phrases.  Establishing a clean sortable string field to sort against works for me.